# NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/cfg/MConfig

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, quartz-scheduler, c3p0

When I update my dependencies I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig
```

Full error Log is Here

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
    at net.intellica.icc.services.Application.main(Application.java:102)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:452)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
    at eans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/cfg/MConfig
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/cfg/MConfig
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config.findLibraryMultiPropertiesConfig(C3P0Config.java:157)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config.<clinit>(C3P0Config.java:143)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.PoolBackedDataSourceBase.<init>(PoolBackedDataSourceBase.java:54)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.<init>(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:74)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractComboPooledDataSource.<init>(AbstractComboPooledDataSource.java:142)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractComboPooledDataSource.<init>(AbstractComboPooledDataSource.java:138)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.<init>(ComboPooledDataSource.java:47)
    at net.intellica.icc.services.Application.dataSource(Application.java:78)
    at net.intellica.icc.services.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90e80993.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>)
    at net.intellica.icc.services.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90e80993$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2d2ccb93.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at net.intellica.icc.services.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90e80993.dataSource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 119 more
```

I update quarts, c3p0 and mchange-commons-java like below

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- <exclusion> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> 
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> </exclusion> -->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.intellica.icc</groupId>
        <artifactId>icc-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.sniggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-pgp-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>teradata-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160807</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdgss</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.2.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mikesamuel</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-sanitizer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

before update it was like below

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- <exclusion> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> 
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> </exclusion> -->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.intellica.icc</groupId>
        <artifactId>icc-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.sniggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-pgp-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>teradata-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160807</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdgss</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.2.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mikesamuel</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-sanitizer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea why I am getting this error

Comment: I had to chop of my error log it was longer normally but I think it reveals the important parts

Comment: In IntelliJ, the mchange-commons-java is unnecessary because Maven grabs that dependancy when it grabs the c3p0. But the com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig class def is in the mchange-commons-java jar. Perhaps remove mchange-commons-java dependancy and replace C3p0 with this:         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: yes it solved the problem. Can you write as answer so I can resolve the topic @theChoosyBeggar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
`mchange-commons-java`
dependancy is unnecessary since it is contained in the
`<groupId>com.mchange</groupId><artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>` dependancy. Replace your `pom.xml` with this:

````
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- <exclusion> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> 
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> </exclusion> -->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.intellica.icc</groupId>
        <artifactId>icc-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.sniggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-pgp-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>teradata-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160807</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdgss</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.2.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mikesamuel</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-sanitizer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```
````